# jQuery to "attach" a div to an li?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a generated unordered list (ul). Later on the page I have a series of DIVS, each div corresponds to an LI in the UL. How would I "attach" these DIVS to the LI items? I mean visually. As if the DIV was "attached" or "snapped" to the bottom of the LI.

I know this would be MUCH easier if I made each div a child UL within the LI and CSS would actually handle that, but the parent UL is being automatically generated without an option to add elements to it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As @Mr_Nizzle suggests, you should manipulate the DOM and put the divs inside the LI (and then use CSS to position it). To only visually attach it would require you to use absolute positioning of the divs based on the offsets of the LIs, and you'd have to re-run this code on every window resize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.append()` http://api.jquery.com/append/

And then you can do something like:

```
$('li#myListItem').append('<div>New Content</div>');
```